# Can't retrieve Object Property from Pushed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am getting problem in script as follows:

**My code**

```
function data (classno) {
    switch (classno) {
       case 0:
         return [
                 {'name' : 'SomeName1', 'age' : 'SomeAge1'},
                 {'name' : 'SomeName2', 'age' : 'SomeAge2'}
         ]
         break;
       case 2:
         return [
                 {'name' : 'SomeName3', 'age' : 'SomeAge3'},
                 {'name' : 'SomeName4', 'age' : 'SomeAge4'}
         ]
    }
}
function add (name, age, classno) {
    var a, b;
    a = {'name' : name, 'age' : age};
    b = data(classno);
    b.push(a);
}
function list (classno) {
    var dt = data(classno),
        body = document.body;
    for (var x=0;x < dt.length;x++) {
         var div = document.createElement('div');
         var div1 = document.createElement('div');
         var tx_name = document.createTextNode(dt[x].name);
         var tx_age = document.createTextNode(dt[x].age);
         div1.appendChild(tx_age);
         div.appendChild(tx_name);
         div.appendChild(div1);
         body.appendChild(div)
    }
}

add('ABC', 12, 0); //Adding User to list...
list(0); //Listing all user in Class number '0'...
```

But, the new user which I added not shown in listed users.

Is there any other way to do so?

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naman00/ktaz14ze/) which I tried.

Comment: `data` returns a ***new*** array every time it's called, so the `add` function has a really confusing name, as it doesn't really add anything, it creates a new array

Comment: the `add` function also is completely wrong it create new array but don't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` always return a new array, there is no variable in which this array is stored so that you can update that array and get the updated data.

check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ktaz14ze/1/) to see how you can do it without creating a variable array but then you won't be able to invoke the list method by passing `classno`.

However, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/ktaz14ze/2/) to see how you can do it with variable array and still use list method by passing `classno`

```
var obj = {
  0: [
                     {'name' : 'SomeName1', 'age' : 'SomeAge1'},
                     {'name' : 'SomeName2', 'age' : 'SomeAge2'}
             ],
  2: [
                     {'name' : 'SomeName3', 'age' : 'SomeAge3'},
                     {'name' : 'SomeName4', 'age' : 'SomeAge4'}
             ]

}

function data (classno) {
        return obj[ classno ];
    }
    function add (name, age, classno) {
        var a, b;
        a = {'name' : name, 'age' : age};
        b = data(classno);
        b.push(a);
    }
    function list (classno) {
        var dt = data(classno),
            body = document.body;
        for (var x=0;x < dt.length;x++) {
             var div = document.createElement('div');
             var div1 = document.createElement('div');
             var tx_name = document.createTextNode(dt[x].name);
             var tx_age = document.createTextNode(dt[x].age);
             div1.appendChild(tx_age);
             div.appendChild(tx_name);
             div.appendChild(div1);
             body.appendChild(div)
        }
    }

    add('ABC', 12, 0); //Adding User to list...
    list(0); //Listing all user in Class number '0'...
```